# Writing a program to find the optimal reward for a 2-armed Bernoulli bandit

Tags: dynamic-programming

(It might be useful to refer to page 9 of Multi-Armed Bandit Allocation Indices by Gittins, Glazebrook and Weber if you have it, because there explanation will be much better than mine.)

I'm trying to write a program that finds that optimal expected reward for a 2-armed Bernoulli bandit process where the first arm has prior probability theta ~ Beta(alpha,beta) of success and the second has a fixed probability p of success, and we have a finite horizon n. The prior is updated via Bayes' theorem after each pull. The reward at the kth pull is gamma^k for a success, and 0 for a failure, where gamma is in [0,1). Using the theory from the book, I've written the following program in R, which utilises dynamic programming:

```
reward = function(alpha,beta,p,gamma,n)
{
if (n==1)
    {
    return(max(alpha/(alpha+beta),p))
    }
else
    {
    success = alpha/(alpha+beta) * (1 + gamma*reward(alpha+1,beta,p,gamma,n-1))
    failure = beta/(alpha+beta) * (gamma*reward(alpha,beta+1,p,gamma,n-1))
    other = p*(1-gamma^n)/(1-gamma)
    return(max(success+failure,other))
    }
}
```

This program tells you the expected optimal reward, and I'm pretty sure it works, since for small N it agrees with my hand calculations. However, this program does not output the sequence of pulls required to obtain the optimal reward. How should I go about modifying this program so as to produce the list of pulls as well?

(For what it's worth, I only know a little of R and MatLab. And sorry if this would be more suited to math.stackexchange)

Edit:

I had already tried to do as Wandering Logic said in matlab, using the following:

```
function [answer] = reward(alpha,beta,p,gamma,n)

global arm k
arm = [];
k = 1;

answer = subreward(alpha,beta,p,gamma,n);
arm
end


function [answer] = subreward(alpha,beta,p,gamma,n)

global arm k

if n==1
    [val,pull] = max([alpha/(alpha+beta),p]);
    answer = val;
    arm(k) = pull;
    k=k+1;
else
    s = alpha/(alpha+beta) * (1 + gamma*subreward(alpha+1,beta,p,gamma,n-1));
    f = beta/(alpha+beta) * (gamma*subreward(alpha,beta+1,p,gamma,n-1));
    o = p*(1-gamma^n)/(1-gamma);
    [val,pull] = max([s+f,o]);
    answer = val;
    arm(k) = pull;
    k=k+1;
end
end
```

However, this stores all 2^n - 1 values, rather than just n values.

Comment: Put each pull in a list, and output the list at the end.

Comment: I've already tried that, but rather than just outputting the n pulls required, it records and outputs the pull for everything involved in the calculation, even if it isn't used in the optimal decision.

Comment: The _return value_ of `reward` should be a pair: <value,list>.  In your `else` clause you will need to do your two calls to `reward`, calculate the better choice, and then return the value and list updated for the better choice.

Comment: I updated my original post. Have you any ideas on how to adapt that?